# How to do parallel testing with peekpoketester in chisel3?

Tags: scala, coroutine, hdl, chisel

I want to write a bus monitor for my design in chisel3 (actually a [mdio bus](https://github.com/Martoni/MDIO)) and I wonder if it's possible to execute this monitor function in parallel to the "main" testbench.
Like we do it in cocotb with [cocotb.fork() coroutine](https://cocotb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/coroutines.html) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support for parallel testing with `chisel3.iotesters` ("Chisel Testers"). However, there is support for parallel testing with the new testing framework: [`chisel3.testers` ("Chisel Testers2")](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers2).

This adds support for `fork`, `join`, and `parallel` constructs. A concise example is testing a queue by [forking both the enqueueing and dequeueing](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers2/blob/5025e93f7940fc458c4d08937f5bcfb7d4bdf338/src/test/scala/chisel3/tests/QueueTest.scala#L46):

```scala
it should "work with a combinational queue" in {
  test(new PassthroughQueue(UInt(8.W))) { c =>
    c.in.initSource()
    c.in.setSourceClock(c.clock)
    c.out.initSink()
    c.out.setSinkClock(c.clock)

    fork {
      c.in.enqueueSeq(Seq(42.U, 43.U, 44.U))
    }.fork {
      c.out.expectDequeueSeq(Seq(42.U, 43.U, 44.U))
    }.join()
  }
}
```

For an additional example, see the `chisel-template` file [`GcdTesters2.scala`](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-template/blob/d37a3371a575570225af82d0064bdb845005d47a/src/test/scala/gcd/GcdTesters2.scala).

Comment: The current master branch of chisel-template has a similar example using chisel-testers2 on a decoupled version of GCD

Comment: Thanks, @ChickMarkley. I updated the answer above with a direct link to that file (using a hard-coded git hash for posterity).